# Какими способами можно вывести уникальные значения из таблицы?

Tags: javascript

Как можно вывести уникальные значения из таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать UNION, EXCEPT, INTERSECT, которые исключают дубликаты.

Comment: Но мне нужно вывести уникальные значения из одной таблицы, а except в таком случае не выведет ничего                                                                                                                                                       SELECT name
FROM News
EXCEPT SELECT name 
FROM News

Comment: А так?  
 SELECT name FROM News EXCEPT SELECT name FROM News where 1=2;

Answer (score 1):

Ну я сходу только один вариант могу придумать/вспомнить:

```
SELECT name FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT top 1 name FROM table t2 WHERE t1.name=t2.name AND t2.id < t1.id)
```

Таким образом по идее должна вывестись запись с минимальным `id` для каждого `name`.